# In Python, what will happen if I pass a normal variable to a function and use apply_async to execute it with multiple processes?

Tags: python, operating-system, multiprocessing

I met some behavior of Python multiprocessing which I cannot understand...

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import sys

def f(x):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(x)
    return x * x

def f2(x, f):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(x, file=f)
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    for t in range(10):
        p.apply_async(f, args=(t,))
    p.close()
    p.join()    # Here it blocks and prints the number, which is normal.

    p = Pool(5)
    for t in range(10):
        p.apply_async(f2, args=(t, sys.stdout))
    p.close()
    p.join()    # Here it does not block and nothing happends(no output at all)...
```

The output is:

```
3
1
0
2
4
5
9
6
7
8
```

I know that we have to use something like shared variables to pass to the function when using multiprocessing and `apply_async`, but what will happen if I pass a normal variable to a function used in `apply_async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.Pool` executes your logic in a separate process. If the logic raises and exception, the `Pool` will return it to the caller.

In your code you are not collecting the output of your functions, therefore you don't notice the real issue.

Try to modify your code as follows:

```
    p = Pool(5)
    for t in range(10):
        task = p.apply_async(f2, args=(t, sys.stdout))
        task.get()
```

You will then get the actual exception which was raised within `f2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 24, in <module>
    p.apply_async(f2, args=(t, sys.stdout)).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

It turns out that `sys.stdout` is not [picklable](http://%20%20%20%20%20Traceback%20(most%20recent%20call%20last):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22asd.py%22,%20line%2024,%20in%20%3Cmodule%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p.apply_async(f2,%20args=(t,%20sys.stdout)).get()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py%22,%20line%20608,%20in%20get%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20raise%20self._value%20%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py%22,%20line%20385,%20in%20_handle_tasks%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20put(task)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py%22,%20line%20206,%20in%20send%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py%22,%20line%2050,%20in%20dumps%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cls(buf,%20protocol).dump(obj)%20%20%20%20%20TypeError:%20cannot%20serialize%20'_io.TextIOWrapper'%20object). Which, in this case, is not an issue as `sys.stdout` unique per process. You can avoid passing it over the function and just use it as is within `f2`.